# Does Haiku cache parameters when combined with jax.vmap?

Tags: caching, jax, haiku

I have a haiku Module with a call function as follows

```py
class MyModule(hk.Module):
    __call__(self, x):
        A = hk.get_parameter("A", shape=[self.Ashape], init=A_init)
        B = hk.get_parameter("B", shape=[self.Bshape], init=B_init)
        C = self.demanding_computation(A, B)

        res = easy_computation(C, x)
        return res
```

I use this module via

```py
def _forward(x):
    module = MyModule()
    return module(x)


forward = hk.without_apply_rng(hk.transform(_forward))
x_test = jnp.ones(1)
params = forward.init(jax.random.PRNGKey(42), x_test)
f = jax.vmap(forward.apply, in_axes=(None, 0))
```

Then I apply f with the same `params` to many different `x`. Is the `demanding_computation` (that is not depending on `x`) then cached within the `jax.vmap` call? If not, what is the correct pattern to separate these computations and get `demanding_computation` cached?

I have tried to test this by adding a print statement from `jax.experimental.host_callback`:

```py
    def demanding_computation(self, A, B):
        C = compute(A, B)
        id_print(C)
        return C
```

and it indeed only printed once. Is that sufficient evidence that this computation is actually cached or is only the printing omitted in subsequent iterations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`demanding_computation` will only be called once, but not because of caching.

`vmap` doesn't loop over the batched axes, it replaces the operations with vectorized versions (e.g. scalar additions become vector additions). Since `demanding_computation` doesn't involve inputs with batch axes it won't be modified by this use of `vmap`. (Even if it did, it would still only be run once, it would just be a vectorized version).